# Will width=\textwidth also automatically scale the height of the original image?

Tags: width, includegraphics, height

For example,

`\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Example.jpg}`

Will the height also been automatically adjusted according to the same ratio of width?

Comment: And welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `width` and `height` keys can be used without the other, in which case the aspect ratio of the image is kept and it is just scaled to that width or height, respectively. So `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{<file>}` and `\includegraphics[height=\textheight]{<file>}` will both keep the aspect ratio.

Another usage would be to use both simultaneously, in which case the image will get distorted to match both dimensions, having the specified `width` and `height`, so `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight]{<file>}` will have exactly those dimensions.

The third variant is to use both and additionally the `keepaspectratio` option. In this case the image will keep its aspect ratio and will be scaled such that it is as big as possible without having a bigger width or height than the specified values, so `\includegraphics[keepaspectratio,width=\textwidth,height=\textheight]{<file>}` will have the biggest possible size while staying in those constraints without being distorted.

An example document using the three variants:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-duck}
\includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image-duck}
\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=4cm]{example-image-duck}
\includegraphics[keepaspectratio,width=5cm,height=4cm]{example-image-duck}
\end{document}
```

[image]